# How create UIHit YesNoNull?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I need create UIHint to be able to connect it to any type, and it worked:
If the checkbox is selected the data are visible if the checkbox is not selected then the data should be hidden and passed null.

But `@Html.EditorForModel()` not worked.

In model:

```
[UIHint("_YesNoNull")]
[DisplayName("Ссылка на место проведения")]
public string VenueUrl { get; set; }
```

_YesNoNull control:

```
@{
    Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
    var propertyName = this.ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName;
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#@(propertyName)_checkbox').click(function () {

            var checked = $(this).attr('checked');
            if (checked != undefined) {
                $(this).val(true);
            }
            else {
                $(this).val(false);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
@Html.CheckBox("checkbox", false)
@Html.EditorForModel()//not worked
```

source html:

```
<div class="editor-label">
            <label for="VenueUrl">Ссылка на место проведения</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#VenueUrl_checkbox').click(function () {

            var checked = $(this).attr('checked');
            if (checked != undefined) {
                //show VenueUrl
            }
            else {
                //hide VenueUrl
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<input id="VenueUrl_checkbox" name="VenueUrl.checkbox" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="VenueUrl.checkbox" type="hidden" value="false" />


            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="VenueUrl" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

what I want to get a result:

```
   <div class="editor-label">
                <label for="VenueUrl">Ссылка на место проведения</label>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#VenueUrl_checkbox').click(function () {

                var checked = $(this).attr('checked');
                if (checked != undefined) {
                    //show VenueUrl
                }
                else {
                    //hide VenueUrl
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <input id="VenueUrl_checkbox" name="VenueUrl.checkbox" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="VenueUrl.checkbox" type="hidden" value="false" />

<div class="editor-field">

<input class="text-box single-line" id="VenueUrl" name="VenueUrl" type="text" value=""/>

</div>
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="VenueUrl" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you calling `@Html.EditorForModel()`inside the UIHint cshtml view? `@Html.CheckBox("checkbox", false)` should suffice...

Comment: you do not understand what I need. checkbox is a separate item in order to be able to hide the open field

Comment: I've never seen a call to `@Html.EditorForModel` within a `UIHint` view template. It's new to me...

Comment: What do you expect the `@Html.EditorForModel()` call to do? What markup do you expect it to render?

Comment: I look forward to prorendarilos field `public string VenueUrl {get; set;}` but the main thing that this method does not depend on the type of data. I want to create something like a wrapper

Comment: **`prorendarilos`**?????? What are you talking about? I didn't understand anything from your description. Could you please go ahead and update your question by posting the expected markup? I guess it will make things more clear.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, I update my post

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
@Html.EditorForModel()//not worked
```

use

```
@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue)
```